# MySQL query execution taking long time in version 8.0.17 compared to version 5.7.26

Tags: mysql, performance

We are running a simple select query with order by clause on a table with 20 million records. When we compared the query execution times, there is a drastic performance degradation in 8.0.17 compared with 5.7.26.

Query Execution Time in MySQL version 5.7.26 :-

mysql> show profile for query 1;

```
+------------------------------+------------+
| Status                       | Duration   |
+------------------------------+------------+
| starting                     |   0.000136 |
| checking permissions         |   0.000022 |
| Opening tables               |   0.000037 |
| init                         |   0.000043 |
| System lock                  |   0.000019 |
| Waiting for table level lock |  10.462425 |
| System lock                  |   0.000055 |
| optimizing                   |   0.000018 |
| statistics                   |   0.000035 |
| preparing                    |   0.000031 |
| Sorting result               |   0.000015 |
| executing                    |   0.000012 |
| Sending data                 |   0.000023 |
| Creating sort index          | 320.189519 |
| end                          |   0.000237 |
| query end                    |   0.001325 |
| closing tables               |   0.000030 |
| freeing items                |   0.000608 |
| cleaning up                  |   0.000044 |
+------------------------------+------------+
```

Query Execution Time in MySQL version 8.0.17 :-

```
mysql> show profile for query 1;
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Status                         | Duration   |
+--------------------------------+------------+
| starting                       |   0.000189 |
| Executing hook on transaction  |   0.000017 |
| starting                       |   0.000025 |
| checking permissions           |   0.000022 |
| Opening tables                 |   0.000072 |
| init                           |   0.000017 |
| System lock                    |   0.000026 |
| optimizing                     |   0.000018 |
| statistics                     |   0.000034 |
| preparing                      |   0.000056 |
| executing                      | 584.276929 |
| end                            |   0.000050 |
| query end                      |   0.071751 |
| closing tables                 |   0.000080 |
| freeing items                  |   0.000096 |
| cleaning up                    |   0.000060 |
```

+--------------------------------+------------+

We tried changing below parameters that did not helped in improving the performance.

```
sort_buffer_size 
read_buffer_size 
read_rnd_buffer_size
myisam_sort_buffer_size
max_allowed_packet
```

Could you please help in improving the performance?

Comment: Please include the query itself, as if it is not tuned properly, this might be the first place to start.

Comment: We are using a simple select query "select * from table order by primarykey";

Comment: OK...but we need to see it :-)

Comment: select * from tablename order by primarykey;

Comment: This query can't be optimized further.

Comment: But why does the performance degraded so much with MySQL 8.0.17? Is there any other configuration change that we need to do to improve the performance?

Comment: Well have you configured that something other than the query is the cause?  Could it be that you have substantially more data in MySQL 8?  Or, could the usage of this table/database be much greater in MySQL 8?

Comment: We have tested with same amount of data in both 5.7.26 and 8.0.17 and there was no change in usage between the two versions.

Comment: Also I have noticed that when we do query profiling, version 5.7.26 shows 'creating sort index' but version 8.0.17 does not show this. Is this something that is not present in MySQL 8.0.17?

Comment: There should be no need to "create a sort index" if you really have `ORDER BY primarykey`.??